# Viewmodels with *and* without IDs?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, viewmodel, objectid

In a typical RESTful application, object `query` and `create` do not include IDs, while `update` and `query result`-children do. Constructing models for these operations presents a design dilemma:

- Create the model without ID, and pass IDs as additional parameters. This doesn't account for serializing indexed lists.
- Create the model with ID, and just rely on maintainers to not wire it up where it shouldn't be. Spotting security flaws is a challenge in this scheme, and model validation is tricky.
- Create the models both with and without IDs (potentially with derivation). The spaghetti viewmodels though...
- Add `IncludesId<TObject,TId>` (perhaps deriving `Dictionary` and `KeyValuePair`) class and custom serialization to projects. This might pair well with resource locators. I haven't given that enough thought yet, just reaching here...

**How do you handle IDs on viewmodels to account for this dual need?**

I included the environment I typically use in the tags, but I don't think the question is really very specific to that environment. Sorry the question is a little open-ended. It's just that after all this time, I still have no practice for managing this that feels clean, so I'm open to ideas.

**Example (by request)**

```
public class AccountController : _ApiController {

    // returns but does not consume Id, dead member to confuse maintainers
    public IEnumerable<AccountViewModel> GetBestMatches(AccountViewModel searchCriteria) { ... }

    // returns Id, but consuming Id adds risk of updating another account
    public AccountViewModel PostRegisterUser(AccountViewModel newAccount) { ... }

    // consumes Id, returning Id is typically unimportant
    [Require(Privilege.AccountEdit)]
    public AccountViewModel PutEditUser(AccountViewModel editedAccount) { ... }

    // Id is derived from current authentication, presence adds maintenance risk
    public AccountViewModel PostEditOwnProfile(AccountViewModel selfAccount) { ... }

    // should not expose/return Id
    [Route("api/Appointment/{appointmentId}/ClientContactInfo")]
    public AccountViewModel GetContactInformation(int appointmentId) { ... }

}
```

In the above example, the technology used is AngularJS -> JSON -> ASP.NET WebAPI2 -> C# -> EntityFramework 6 -> SQL Server 2012

Comment: Can you please describe your application? How is the viewmodel used? How does the fontend talk to your backend? How do you talk to your database? Which technology do you use for that? Do you have some kind of ORM?

Comment: Sure, derape. I've added an example. If my edit doesn't help, please let me know. I hate to add too much unrelated text in the question for quality reasons.

Comment: Does the data that is presented contain enough to form a natural key? Other alternatives are to use a token ID (hash or guid, for ex.) that is x-ref'd to the real ID in session state. In the same x-ref you can store a timestamp to 'expire' the token if it is presented in a subsequent request too far into the future.

Comment: Keith. I've often thought about using surrogate surrogate keys. From a security perspective, it's a big improvement. However, it doesn't really eliminate most of the risks and just general maintenance confusion that can arise from uninitialized keys being passed around. I like your idea of natural keys as a solution. In the example above for instance, in an ideal world you'd like e-mail addresses to be unique, and can even demand it in your data. However, that causes more problems than it solves to rely on it as a key. And it's one of many scenarios where this ID dilemma arises.